# Rails 4, Devise - sign in redirect paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, path

I am trying to make an app in rails 4.

I have tried to make an after sign in path in my application controller to redirect users.

When I sign into devise with a new session (via my omniauth callbacks controller), I expect to go to my profile page. Profile#show is the page I'm wanting to go to in those circumstances. Each user has one profile (and profile belongs to user).

If I authenticate from a page that requires authentication, the request referer works to redirect to that page.

In circumstances when my email is verified, I am still getting the finish sign up path (although all of the form fields in that form other than the submit button) are not rendered). If the email is verified, then the finish sign up path should not be the redirect.

Instead, I am sent to the root path.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if !resource.email_verified? 
          finish_signup_path(resource)
        elsif params[:redirect_to].present?
          store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
        elsif  request.referer == new_session_path(:user)
          profile_path(resource.profile) # or whatever the route is for the destination you want
        else
          stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path 
      end 
    end

def set_redirect_path
    @redirect_path = request.path
  end
```

Omniauth callbacks controller has:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  #sourcey tutorial ------------------

  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user) 

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user,  event: :authentication


        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end


  [:twitter, :facebook, :linkedin, :google_oauth2].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end



end
```

User.rb callback method is:

```
def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
    # Get the identity and user if they exist
    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

    # If a signed_in_resource is provided it always overrides the existing user
    # to prevent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
    # Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity) which
    # can be cleaned up at a later date.
    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    # p '11111'

    # Create the user if needed
    if user.nil?
      # p 22222
      # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
      # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
      # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
      email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified # take out this if stmt for chin yi's solution
      user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

      # Create the user if it's a new registration
      if user.nil?
        # p 33333
        user = User.new(
          # at least one problem with this is that each provider uses different terms to desribe first name/last name/email. See notes on linkedin above
          first_name: auth.info.first_name,
          last_name: auth.info.last_name,
          email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
          #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
# fallback for name fields - add nickname to user table
        # debugger

        # if email_is_verified
           user.skip_confirmation!
        # end
        # user.skip_confirmation! 

        user.save!
      end
    end

    # Associate the identity with the user if needed
    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end
    user
  end

  def email_verified?
    self.email && TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX !~ self.email
  end
```

Comment: Can you add your `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` file here.

Comment: Also, the `user.rb` file

Comment: I can see you have followed sourcey tutorial, please follow the wiki for Omniauth with Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview you will understand where is the issue coming from.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really helpful. I have been trying to set devise/omniauth up for 3 years. The omniauth docs are full of errors and assumptions. You can see from the 30+ bounties I have posted for help in setting up these functions the issues I've outlined. I'd appreciate if you can share the issue you've identified.

Comment: I can understand its a bit complex to crack on the first place..lets start from the scratch. I know you have spent lot of time figuring out ways but they way I have figured it out is little bit different than this one and i am sure this time it wont take much time. lets join over a chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101897/rails-implement-omniauth-with-devise here is the link. I have created a chat room, let me know what is good time to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I put the profile path redirect into the final string of options before root path, instead of having it as a separate else statement (which I now think conflicts with the sign in redirect path where there is a request referer.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if !resource.email_verified? or !resource.first_name.present? or !resource.last_name.present?
          finish_signup_path(resource)
        elsif params[:redirect_to].present?
          store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
        else
          stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || profile_path(resource.profile) ||root_path 
      end 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple yet effective solution on Github [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out).

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 stored_location_for(resource) || profile_path
end
```

It is also stated that in order for the above to work, your root path must be publicly visible. For example, adding this to you "pages_controller"...

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except:  [:landing]
```